# Block: DRUPAL_NO_CACHE not working

Tags: 7, blocks, caching

I have a block that displays an item fetched from the database at random. The block has DRUPAL_NO_CACHE as cache parameter. However, when visiting the page as anonymous user with the cache on, the item never changes.

Some code:

```
function foo_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();

  $blocks['foo'] = array(
    'info' => t('Foo'), 
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function foo_block_view($delta = '') {
  if ($delta == 'foo') {
    $block = array(
      'content' => theme(
        'foo_block',
          array(
            'item' => entity_get_controller('foo')->get_random_foo(),
          )
        ),
    );
    return $block;
  }
}

function foo_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'foo_block' => array(
      'template' => 'foo-block',
      'arguments' => array(
        'item' => NULL,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I suspect it's a Drupal Core bug, I've checked the forums but can't really find a solution for Drupal 7.

I know I could insert the item in the DOM with AJAX, but that's a last resort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are caching the whole page ([which is off by default in D7](http://www.smartt.com/sites/default/files/public/imce/janiec/Drupal%20caching%20performance.png)) then BLOCK_NO_CACHE will not make a difference on a block. Because while the block is not cached, the page is.

I think what you may want is the [esi api module](http://drupal.org/project/esi_api) it allows you to use ajax to render the blocks.

Comment: In what situations would DRUPAL_NO_CACHE or it's D6's variant be useful? When the cache is off there wouldn't be a reason to set the block cache to DRUPAL_NO_CACHE anyway (since it's not cached).

Comment: I may be wrong, but block cache is independent of page cache. If you really need to have no caching for the block you should specify it. Otherwise you get DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE

Comment: As Jeremy said, block caching applies when there is *no* page cache or when a page cache needs to be rebuilt. Remember that a page cache entry is for a specific URL, but you might be displaying the same cached block on every/multiple pages.