# Clear block cache in panels page

Tags: 7, blocks, panels, caching

I'm having trouble with refreshing content in a block created with a custom module, placed within a panels page. My end goal is to display either regular or seasonal hours based on a set date range. My `hook_theme()` implementation looks like the following:

```
function daily_hours_theme() {
  if (daily_hours_is_summer()) {
    $table_template = daily_hours_get_summer_vars();
  } else {
    $table_template = daily_hours_get_regular_vars();
  }
  $items =  array(
    'todays_hours_table' => $table_template,
    'daily_hours_text_content' => array(
      'render element' => 'element',
    )
  );
  return $items;
}
```

I'm using `hook_block_info()` to test cache settings; the following doesn't seem to have an effect on caching:

```
function daily_hours_block_info() {
  $blocks['hours_table'] = array(
    'info' => t('Daily Hours Table'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}
```

And `hook_block_view()` to call the theme function:

```
function daily_hours_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'hours_table':
      $block['content'] = theme('todays_hours_table');
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Ideally, I'd clear the module's block data at midnight every day, but I'd settle for just knowing how to implement any caching rules in this context.

Comment: If you place the block outside the panel, same result?

Comment: Like if I add it via the normal block interface rather than panels? Yes, the content is still caching.

Comment: could this be the answer [Block: DRUPAL_NO_CACHE not working](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6622/block-drupal-no-cache-not-working) ?

Comment: I don't believe so - I don't have either "Cache pages for anonymous users" or "Cache blocks" set to be true on /admin/config/development/performance.

Comment: `I don't have either "Cache pages for anonymous users" or "Cache blocks" set to be true` Then it's very odd that your blocks are caching. Are you using Varnish/Redis or some other caching contrib module/tool ?

Comment: No. The logic for displaying different content is within the theme function. Is there some way to ensure variables are not cached there?

Answer (score 0):

The variables were being cached at some point in the `hook_theme()` function, so after reading the [documentation on `hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7.x), I moved the logic to conditionally use different variables in to my `hook_block_view()` implementation, passing them in to the call to `theme()` at that point. So that function looks like the following:

```
function daily_hours_block_view($delta = '') {
  if (daily_hours_is_summer()) {
    $variables = daily_hours_get_summer_vars();
  } else {
    $variables = daily_hours_get_regular_vars();
  }
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'hours_table':
      $block['content'] = theme('todays_hours_table', $variables);
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

And my `hook_theme()` function:

```
function daily_hours_theme() {
   $items =  array(
     'todays_hours_table' => array(
       'template' => 'hours_table',
       'variables' => array(
          // set default variables here
       )
     )
   );
   return $items;
 }
```

The cache setting in my `hook_block_info()` implementation did not seem to have an impact once I set up the logic in the `hook_block_view()` function.